# What formula is used for standard deviation in R?

Tags: r, standard-deviation

What formula is used in the standard deviation function `sd` in R?

Comment: Generally, you will be able to read the function's code by simply calling it without parenthesis, as Gschneider did.

Comment: @OweJessen While true, this is often not as helpful as one might think. Many functions in R are just wrappers that call underlying C code. For example, sd leads you to var, which leads you to .Call(C_cov, x, y, na.method, FALSE).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As pointed out by @Gschneider, it computes the sample standard deviation

$$\sqrt{\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})^2}{n-1}}$$

which you can easily check as follows:

```
> #generate a random vector
> x <- rnorm(n=5, mean=3, sd=1.5)
> n <- length(x)
> 
> #sd in R
> sd1 <- sd(x)
> 
> #self-written sd
> sd2 <- sqrt(sum((x - mean(x))^2) / (n - 1))
>  
> #comparison
> c(sd1, sd2)   #:-)
[1] 0.6054196 0.6054196
```

Comment: If you look at the help page (?sd), it says "Like var, this uses denominator n-1", if for some reason you don't believe ocram's simulation :-)

Comment: @ Matt: Maybe they should update that help file and say something like "this returns the sqrt of var" ?

Comment: @OweJessen, I think it actually says that "var returns its square!"

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal for learning why this simulation could give *different* results for both functions.

Comment: Another simple way to test it is `sd( c(-1,0,1) )` which outputs 1.

Answer (score 13):

Yes. Technically, it computes the sample variance, and then takes the square root:

```
> sd
function (x, na.rm = FALSE) 
{
if (is.matrix(x)) 
    apply(x, 2, sd, na.rm = na.rm)
else if (is.vector(x)) 
    sqrt(var(x, na.rm = na.rm))
else if (is.data.frame(x)) 
    sapply(x, sd, na.rm = na.rm)
else sqrt(var(as.vector(x), na.rm = na.rm))
}
```